# How to get private key from hardhat ethers signer?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

In hardhat I'd like to get the *privateKey* from a signer, the *privateKeys* are initialised in the *hardhat.config* `networks.network.accounts`.

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Signer } from "ethers";

const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
const account0: Signer = accounts[0];
```

I don't see any attribute/method on the `Signer` instance to get the *privateKey*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the private keys from the network config (`localhost`, `mainnet`, etc):

```typescript
import { config } from "hardhat";

console.log('Accounts from config:', config.networks.mainnet.accounts);
```

In case you want to get the private keys for hardhat accounts:

```typescript
const accounts = config.networks.hardhat.accounts;
const index = 0; // first wallet, increment for next wallets
const wallet1 = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(accounts.mnemonic, accounts.path + `/${index}`);

const privateKey1 = wallet1.privateKey
...
```

Here is an example, how I use this:

https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/8bab2114875b055f5f6ea361951d0d7083f3259c/src/hardhat/HardhatProvider.ts#L41

Comment: Thanks for this, however the default hardhat accounts i.e. config.networks.hardhat.accounts is an HD Wallet config, is there a simple way to get all the private keys from that config?

{
  initialIndex: 0,
  count: 20,
  path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
  passphrase: '',
  mnemonic: 'test test test test test test test test test test test junk',
  accountsBalance: '10000000000000000000000'
}

Comment: See the updated answer. This was smth you want?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it, though I got the private keys by simple starting the hardhat node which logs all the private keys for all 20 accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, think on connecting ether.js with some wallet. The private key wouldn’t be passed to the library because than it could be stolen. **The library issues a request to the wallet to sign the transaction.**

So the private key isn’t stored inside Signer.